# Where do I find boot log in Debian 8 (to debug autostart issues)?

Tags: debian, startup

I am trying to debug why certain apps fail to **autostart** (autostart package).

Premise: **My final goal is to understand why the autostart sequence is broken** (probably due to certain packages' autostart fail). Debian 8 itself boots normally but autostart features doesn't work properly.

So i wanted to go through boot's log (in /var/log/daemon I didn't find what I'm looking for).

According to [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd), I should fine boot log at **/var/log/boot** without any configuration in Debian 8.

However the file is not there.

The wiki also says:

> If you use systemd as your init system, you may need to use `systemctl` to [debug boot problems](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/).

So I tried with

> sudo systemd

but I get an error

> Trying to run as user instance, but $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set.

Comment: Are you talking about the [fbautostart](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/fbautostart) package? There is no other jessie packages [with autostart in their name](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=autostart&searchon=names&suite=jessie&section=all).

Comment: `journalctl -b`

Comment: @MartinUeding thanks for your answer. I tried running the command. Result: No journal files were found.

Comment: @dragonmnl I one created the directory `/var/log/journal` in order to get a persistent systemd journal across boots. But `journalctl` should still write something to memory.

Comment: thank you. I tried to create the directory myself. I'll see if makes it write something

Comment: Apparently having created the file manually got something logged. I see errors but no reference to a specific program. Besides trying to disable program by program to see where the issue is (the fact is that the issue doesn't come up all the times...), is it possible to use journalctl to have information on which specific program caused the issue? thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Debian Jessie is using [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), so there is no longer an `/var/log/boot` file.

You can still obtain a lot of information on the boot process with the command `dmesg`.

But if you use [fbautostart](https://launchpad.net/fbautostart), as I suppose, your problem should appear during the start of the window manager. As fbautostart is relatively trivial the best way, is probably to start by commenting everything, then commenting out, i.e. uncomment, each lines of your configuration files, step by step until you find your problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer. dmesg shows some interesting stuff indeed (but in form of timestamp since boot unfortunately, so I can't see the time when it's something like 35846.36.......). 
Could you please better explain the fbautostart part? (in particular: commentin out...)  I have an autostart package called simply 'autostart' and built-in Debian 8

Comment: Can you edit your question and publish the content of your `autostart` file?

Comment: I've modified my answer trying to be more explicit.

Comment: To be honest I don't really get the fbautostart part. however I accept the answer for the offer. as for dmesg seems interesting. I'll go deeper into it

Answer (score 8):

`sudo journalctl` in Jessie outputs the boot window details including the Warnings and Errors. I have found it to be most helpful in fixing errant packages that systemd starts or attempts to start. It is located at `/bin/journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well for me. Note that if you only want to see warnings, errors, critical and alert messages, you can add the priority parameter like so: `journalctrl -p 4`. If you only want errors and above, make that a `-p 3`.